# How to assign/parse JSON data from 1 as file to another?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parsing, actionscript

and trying to create this search form with a few fields and a search button,when search button is clicked, it goes to next page to display the results and place the results into boxes. E.g. Result 1 has(name,Location,zip), result 2(name,Location,zip) etc

What i need is, php to search and echo the data in JSON, and AS3 VO to receive the data in JSON, Split the data and parse the data to the Vector file and then put them into boxes.

I believe i am just missing 1 final step, i can get the JSON into AS3, i can trace the data. But i can't get it from the first AS(searchVO) file into the Vector AS(SEarchVector) file. 
Please give me some opinion thanks.

AS3 VO(receiving the JSON)

```
function Asandler(event:Event):void{

 trace( event.target.data );

    var resultString  :String = event.target.data;
    // parse result string as json object
    var resultObject  :Object  = JSON.parse(  resultString );
    // loop all keys in the object
    for( var s:String in resultObject )
    {

        switch(s)
        {
            case 'nobed'
                :'nobed', resultObject[s] ;

                break;

            case 'zip'
                :zip=( 'zip', resultObject[s] );

                break;

            case 'Location'
                :Location=( 'Location', resultObject[s] );

                break;

            case 'price'
                :price=( 'price', resultObject[s] );

                break;

        }}}
```

SearchVector

```
public class SearchVectorTest extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function SearchVectorTest() 
        {
            super();

            // This part is the parser, i assume i just have to fix this part and the JSON data will come through, but not sure how

        var test:Vector.<searchVO1> = new Vector.<searchVO1>();

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            {
                var tests:searchVO1 = new searchVO1();
                tests.nobed = nobed ;
                tests.zip = zip;
                tests.Location = Location[i];
                tests.price = price[i];
                test.push(tests);
            }



            // using that we can loop through every book in the entry




                for (var j:int = 0; j < test.length; j++) 
            {
                trace(test[j].nobed);
                trace(test[j].zip);
                trace(test[j].Location);
                trace(test[j].price);
                test[j].nobed;
                test[j].zip;
                test[j].Location;
                test[j].price;

            }






            //  loop and put the text into boxes

            var currentY:int = 270;

            for (var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing5 = new Listing5();

                Bolder.x=80;

                var bf:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf3:TextField = new TextField();

                bf3.width = 100;
                bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                bf.width = 100;
                bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf1.width = 100;
                bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.width = 100;
                bf1.y= bf.height+5;



                    // Pulling the textfields content out from the current bookVO

                bf.text = test[k].nobed;
                bf1.text = test[k].zip;
                bf2.text = test[k].Location;
                bf3.text = test[k].price;

                bf1.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5

                bf3.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5


                bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5
                bf.y = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.15
                Bolder.addChild(bf);
                Bolder.addChild(bf1);
                Bolder.addChild(bf2);
                Bolder.addChild(bf3);


                    // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
                Bolder.y = currentY;


                //visualAssetForBook.y = (visualAssetForBook.height+15)*k;
                addChild(Bolder);
                currentY += Bolder.height + 35;
            }

        }   
    }

}
```

Just tried it and it has 2 error, 
On this line

`searchVOs[i] = new searchVO1(resultArray[i].nobed, resultArray[i].zip, resultArray[i].Location, resultArray[i].price );`   in the searchVO file. 
Error says `Incorrect number of arguments. Expect no more than 0`.

And 1 line below that, `createBoxes(searchVOs);` it has an error,

```
Call to a possibly undefined method createBoxes.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to pass it as VO it's better to use the following solution:

PHP:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// create your output array
$output = array();

// fetch your results
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) !== false )
{
    // add result row to your output's next index
    $output[] = $row;
}

// echo the json encoded object
echo json_encode( $output );
```

and now you can retrieve your result directly as follow:

SearchVO.as:

```
package
{
    public class SearchVO
    {
        public var nobed        :String;
        public var zip          :String;
        public var location     :String;
        public var price        :Number;

        public function SearchVO( nobed:String, zip:String, location:String, price:Number )
        {
            this.nobed      = nobed;
            this.zip        = zip;
            this.location   = location;
            this.price      = price;
        }
    }
}
```

ASHandler function:

```
// retrieve data from php call
var resultString :String = event.target.data;
// parse result string as json object and cast it to array
var resultArray  :Array  = JSON.parse( resultString ) as Array;
// get the length of the result set
var len:int = resultArray.length;

// create vector of SearchVO
var searchVOs:Vector.<SearchVO> = new Vector.<SearchVO>();
// loop the result array
for( var i:int = 0; i<len; ++i )
{
    searchVOs[i] = new SearchVO(resultArray[i].nobed, resultArray[i].zip, resultArray[i].Location, resultArray[i].price );   
}

// call a function to create your boxes
createBoxes(searchVOs);
// or maybe create your SearchVector class and pass it your search vector
var mySearchVector:SearchVector = new SearchVector(searchVOs);
```

createBoxes function:

```
    private function createBoxes( test:vector.<SearchVO> ):void
    {
        //  loop and put the text into boxes

        var currentY:int = 270;

        for( var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++ ) 
        {
            var Bolder:Listing5 = new Listing5();

            Bolder.x=80;

            var bf:TextField = new TextField();
            var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
            var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
            var bf3:TextField = new TextField();

            bf3.width = 100;
            bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

            bf.width = 100;
            bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            bf1.width = 100;
            bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            bf3.width = 100;
            bf1.y= bf.height+5;



            // Pulling the textfields content out from the current bookVO

            bf.text = test[k].nobed;
            bf1.text = test[k].zip;
            bf2.text = test[k].Location;
            bf3.text = test[k].price;

            bf1.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5

            bf3.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5


            bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5
            bf.y = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.15
            Bolder.addChild(bf);
            Bolder.addChild(bf1);
            Bolder.addChild(bf2);
            Bolder.addChild(bf3);


            // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
            Bolder.y = currentY;


            //visualAssetForBook.y = (visualAssetForBook.height+15)*k;
            addChild(Bolder);
            currentY += Bolder.height + 35;
        }
    }
```

or SearchVector Class:

```
public class SearchVectorTest extends MovieClip 
{

    public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<SearchVO>) 
    {
        super();

        // This part is the parser, i assume i just have to fix this part and the JSON data will come through, but not sure how

        // REMOVE THAT !
        /*
    var test:Vector.<searchVO1> = new Vector.<searchVO1>();

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            var tests:searchVO1 = new searchVO1();
            tests.nobed = nobed ;
            tests.zip = zip;
            tests.Location = Location[i];
            tests.price = price[i];
            test.push(tests);
        }
        */


        // using that we can loop through every book in the entry
        for (var j:int = 0; j < test.length; j++) 
        {
            trace(test[j].nobed);
            trace(test[j].zip);
            trace(test[j].Location);
            trace(test[j].price);
            // trace if you want but calling variable just for fun is not usefull
            /*
            test[j].nobed;
            test[j].zip;
            test[j].Location;
            test[j].price;
            */
        }

        //  loop and put the text into boxes

        var currentY:int = 270;

        for (var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++) 
        {
            var Bolder:Listing5 = new Listing5();

            Bolder.x=80;

            var bf:TextField = new TextField();
            var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
            var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
            var bf3:TextField = new TextField();

            bf3.width = 100;
            bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

            bf.width = 100;
            bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            bf1.width = 100;
            bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            bf3.width = 100;
            bf1.y= bf.height+5;

            // Pulling the textfields content out from the current bookVO

            bf.text = test[k].nobed;
            bf1.text = test[k].zip;
            bf2.text = test[k].Location;
            bf3.text = test[k].price;

            bf1.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5

            bf3.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5


            bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.5
            bf.y = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.15
            Bolder.addChild(bf);
            Bolder.addChild(bf1);
            Bolder.addChild(bf2);
            Bolder.addChild(bf3);


            // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
            Bolder.y = currentY;


            //visualAssetForBook.y = (visualAssetForBook.height+15)*k;
            addChild(Bolder);
            currentY += Bolder.height + 35;
        }

    }   
}
```

In all solutions you have to pass the array (or vector) to a function, you cannot retrieve it from nowhere like you do in this part of code:

```
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            var tests:searchVO1 = new searchVO1();
            tests.nobed = nobed ;  // nobed don't exists here
            tests.zip = zip;       // zip don't exists here
            tests.Location = Location[i]; // Location don't exists here and so Location[i]
            tests.price = price[i]; // pricedon't exists here and so price[i]
            test.push(tests);
        }
```

I hope this could help you

PS: try use capital letters on begin of word only for class names and use lowercase start letters for variables. It's more clear for everyone ;) (ex: MyClassName, myVarName)

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for such detailed explanations, i will have to test it out after work later, unfortunately i have to get up for work at 5.45am. But Thanks in Advance, will give that ago in a few hours!

Comment: Hi I just tried the code, i have 2 errors,I will edit the question to display it(make it easier to see), and place it here too   1 is on this line searchVOs[i] = new searchVO1(resultArray[i].nobed, resultArray[i].zip, resultArray[i].Location, resultArray[i].price );   in searchVO file. Error says Incorrect number of arguments. Expect no more than 0. And 1 line below that, createBoxes(searchVOs); it has an error, Call to a possibly undefined method createBoxes.

Comment: as i write in comment at the end of ASHandler function code: 'call a function to create boxes' and i give you the function right after and the comment of the next line: 'OR maybe create your SearchVector class and pass it your search vector' and i give you the modified SearchVector class after int the answer. As you can see in the SearchVectorTest class i give to you i added test:Vector.<SearchVO> in the constructor so you can pass in the vector of your result and use it for the following code

Comment: I tried it for a few days, but i have error in the page that holds the searchVectorTest, it gives an Error says Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1. It is not inside the VO or Vecttest file but the page that holds the VectTest boxes and results. I am not sure what does that error means. On this line var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(); inside the as file that holds that when i tried to add the SearchVectTest inside

Comment: if you corrected you SerachVectorTest class like i show you in the answer, the constructor take a Vector.<SearchVO> as argument so it's normal to have an error if you try to instanciate without it.